# Is there any way to dynamically plot graphs from GNUPLOT at the command line?

Tags: command, gnuplot

I have been using gnuplot and now I want a program in to run gnuplot from command line and directly plot the graph. 
Something like:

```
gnuplot>plot sin(x)
```

However I always have to run gnuplot and then write the plot command.

Comment: You are asking for command line parameters to draw some graph with a specific program. Where is the C part of your question? Or why did you add the C tag if there is none?

Comment: My mistake. Edited.

Comment: Are you aware of [this explanation](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/487/plot-your-graphs-with-command-line-gnuplot/)?

Comment: yes. But I don't want to use a file to plot a graph. I have an equation and I want to plot it directly. @Gerhardh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the man page states:

> -e "command list" executes the requested commands before loading the next input file.

So in your particular case, it seems to me that what you are after is:

```
gnuplot -e "plot sin(x)"
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. And to make the output stay longer we need to use the - persist as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could also run Gnuplot as a co-process to your shell, e.g. with `bash`:

```
coproc gnuplot
```

Now you can send commands to the Gnuplot process through the file descriptor found in `${COPROC[1]}`, e.g.:

```
echo 'plot sin(x)' >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Or if you save the file descriptor value in `p`:

```
p=${COPROC[1]}
echo 'plot sin(x)' >&$p
```

See [*Stephane's* answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372/17666) for other shells and alternative notation.